# How to select points within polygon constrained by field?

Tags: python, arcpy, select-by-attribute

I've created a polygon from a raster dataset:

```
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(RasterInt, "C:/arc/poly_int.shp", "NO_SIMPLIFY", "Value")
```

The 'value' field has numbers 1-37, which map to the ID field in the output polygon shapefile feature class.

Now I would like to select points that lay within certain polygons (e.g. delineated by ID). Using the `SelectLayerByLocation_management` tool only selects points inside all the polygons. How to a define a criteria?

Alternative approach: How do I create multiple polygons from the main polygon, using the ID field?

I'm looking for solutions in Python -- not necessarily using arcpy but I do have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do a SelectLayerByAttribute on your polygons (from raster) prior to using SelectLayerByLocation.

The Select_analysis tool could be useful to your alternative approach.

Comment: I'm new with arcpy, are you saying I could do something along the lines of: `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("MaalestDnmiSF", "WITHIN", arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute(..."test"))`

Comment: It works! `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("stations", "WITHIN", arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("test", "NEW_SELECTION", '"ID" = 21'))
`